# Smooth scrolling with intersection observer in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been trying to snap scroll to sections in angular - achieve similar behavior like snap-scroll-type but using js.

(I can't use snap scroll type because all of my sections are seperate components)

Currently the best solution i have found is using an intersectional observer.
But the issue is that it works only with instant scrolling (from my nav-links smooth scrolling works fine)
My guess is that the user scrolling is somehow interfering with the smooth scroll.

What I am trying to do:

Next section is in view more than treshold -> smooth scrolls to next section

Previous section is in view more than threshold -> smooth scrolls to prev section

Heres my code for nav component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  public activeSection: string = "landing";
  private sections: HTMLElement[] = [];

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(){

  this.sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.section'));

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {

  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      //change active link
      this.activeSection = entry.target.id
      entry.target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto',
      block: 'start', 
      inline: 'nearest'
      });
    }       
  });
  }, 
  {threshold: 0.4});
    
  this.sections.forEach(section => observer.observe(section));
  }

  scrollToSection(link: HTMLAnchorElement, sectionId: string) {
    //get section when link is clicked
    const element = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    //if section exists scroll to section
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start', 
      inline: 'nearest'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

So what i am looking for is being able to smooth scroll with this logic
(of course currently my snap scroll interferes with with navlinks but that i can probably fix with timeouts and flags)

Thanks in advance - been fighting with this for 3 days straight :')